# How to assign project in Mantis?

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, mantis

I am going to ask you this question here since I cannot find answer anywhere else. Sorry if its stupid.

I have created one additional Category: "Programming"

Then two projects: "Project #1" and "Project #2" (both public)

I also have two developer accounts and I am trying to assign Project 1 to first guy and Project 2 to a second one.

Firstly, I believe there is no possibility to select project when you create issue, only Category, so whenever I select "Programming" both developers in issues get assigned to Project #1. Always.

How to make it right?

Please advise.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are usually "in" a project already when you create an issue. The currently selected project is in the drop-down in the upper right hand corner for my version. You must manually switch projects before creating a new issue or viewing issues or really perform any other task.

Second, if there are only two developers and all bugs for a project should be assigned to them you can set it up so all bugs are automatically assigned to them in the project management (manage link) page.

I would post more details but I'm using an older version of mantis and I'm not sure if the screens or links have changed.

Comment: Another question for you - how do I make projects private for each developer?

Comment: I've never done it. Sorry :(. To me, making projects private defeats the purpose of a collaboration and bug reporting tool. You'll have to read the mantis documentation to see if its possible.

Comment: I can not find how to assign default user for new issues. Is description in answer is not relevant any more 2 years later? Thanks.

Comment: I was using an old version when I responded to this 2 years ago. It is likely the screens have changed. I would make a new question and mention that this answer doesn't help you.